# What is encryption in Mifare Classic?

Tags: encryption, mifare

We are designing a micro-payment application.

For some financial reasons, we can't go with DESFire cards. We are thinking then about using Mifare Plus or Mifare Classic.

Our use case is that a client would have a card to recharge and then use to pay on some NFC terminals.

In our workflow, we are storing nothing on the cards. We rely only on the UID of each card to identify a client. All the operations (identification, balance computation, etc...) are then handled on the server side.

Our chips supplier is talking about whether we want encryption or not. but we don't clearly understand.

What is encryption in Mifare Classic? Does it refer to encrypting the data we may store on the chip? If it's the case, we are clearly not concerned about it since we not storing anything on the card or does it include also encrypting the UID?

Comment: We can only tackle one question at a time. I've reduced this to just the Mifare question, and removed the design review.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/56452/is-it-good-idea-to-rely-on-mifare-uid-for-security-authorization-reasons